Mandarin Chinese phonology: on the issue of p/b, t/d, k/g distinction and older romanization systems
Like many people, I've found it intriguing that older Chinese romanization systems such as Wade-Giles and postal romanization seem to "confuse" certain sounds, such as p/b, k/g, and t/d. I originally attributed this to basis on non-Mandarin dialects such as Cantonese, but later learned that these are in fact based on Mandarin, and that the confusing choice of letters comes from subtle distinctions between aspirated and unaspirated consonants.
The problem is, I don't understand how these sounds are any different from English or other major Latin alphabet languages. I was also surprised to learn that based on according to official definitions, the consonants of Pinyin don't map as directly on to English as I thought.  For example, it seems like Pinyin "b" is supposed to be more like English "p". (Really?)
I don't have a background in linguistics, but I'm a native-level speaker of both (standard American) English and Mandarin Chinese, and to me, the sounds b/p/k/g/t/d are exactly the same between English and Chinese.
For example, to my ears the initial sound in 瀑(pù)/不(bù) is exactly the same as in poop/boot, and likewise for 掰(bāi)/拍(pāi) and by/pie.  Is there really supposed to be a difference?  Is it my mind playing tricks on me, as a bilingual speaker?
As a sidenote: in foreign language learning in both directions (i.e. Chinese speakers learning English, and English speakers learning Chinese), it seems that the sounds p/b, t/d, k/g are straightforward and are rarely things that people struggle with.
I do understand that in the case of Wade-Giles, much of the confusion arises from apostrophes that are often omitted. But I don't understand the point of the apostrophes in the first place, when the use of distinct Latin letters (p/b, etc), as done in Pinyin, would be simpler.

The first thing you seem to be misunderstanding is that the tables in the Wikipedia article you link to show sounds in IPA, which is not the same as English. The initial sound in English bye is (mostly) IPA [b], which is a voiced sound; conversely, that in 白 bái is unvoiced, which in IPA is written [p]. But this [p] is not the same as the initial sound in English pie or Mandarin 拍 pāi – that one is also aspirated and written [pʰ] in IPA. So En. ⟨p⟩ = Ch. ⟨p⟩, but En. ⟨b⟩ ≠ Ch. ⟨b⟩.

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for pointing that out, but I think those are "higher-order" issues.  To be clear: to me, 白=bye, and 拍=pie (modulo tone and subtle vowel differences, of course).  This seems to contradict the "official" definition.  Examples like this are what I am confused about.

The second thing is that many earlier transcription schemes were not based on English, but on other European languages like French or Portuguese, where ⟨b⟩ = IPA [b] and ⟨p⟩ = IPA [p]. In other words, the initial sound in French pas is [p] and (more or less) identical with Mandarin 八 bā. In these languages, the aspirated sound denoted by initial ⟨p⟩ in English and Pinyin don’t exist at all, so they had to come with some ‘extra’ way to indicate those, and they generally chose either ⟨h⟩ or ⟨‘⟩.

No, it doesn’t contradict those definitions. The voicing distinction that makes English and Mandarin ⟨b⟩ slightly different can to some extent be ignored, because neither English nor Mandarin distinguishes voiced [b] from unvoiced [p] phonemically. If we do that, we arrive at a situation where bye = 白 and pie = 拍, and that is correct. In English, it’s customary to write the phonemes /b/ and /p/ because that matches the existing spelling (and because /b/ is often voiced, though not always), but Mandarin has no such limitation, so it’s customary to use /p/ and /pʰ/ instead.

But if we pretend for a second that initial /b/ in English is unvoiced (which it actually is sometimes), then the English phonemes /b/ and /p/ correspond to the sounds [p] and [pʰ] in exactly the same way that the Mandarin phonemes /p/ and /pʰ/ correspond to the sounds [p] and [pʰ].

Thanks, this is starting to make sense. I suppose a similar story applies for t/d and k/g?

Yes, exactly the same for those!

And you say "Mandarin has no such limitation, so it’s customary to ..." Perhaps this is a legacy of the pre-Pinyin (i.e. Wade-Giles) era, where it would have made sense to use the letter p in both places? But nowadays it would have the opposite effect, since Pinyin would be entrenched in the minds of anyone who learned Chinese outside of Taiwan.

I meant rather that, when IPA was first adopted roughly a century ago, it was primarily based in French and English linguistic communities, so the letters used to represent sounds are based on how those sounds are represented in those languages (for [b p], French rather than English). When a language already has an established orthography that uses letters also found in IPA, like English, that tends, in turn, to influence how phonemes are represented in IPA for that language. But Mandarin doesn’t have an established orthography like that, so they just used the actual IPA values.

See also https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/48296/whats-the-difference-between-voiceless-and-unaspirated

English /b p/ aren't very different from Mandarin Chinese /p pʰ/, respectively, and it's certainly wrong to say that Pinyin "b" is supposed to be more like English "p". Sometimes people will say Mandarin "b" is pronounced like the P in English "spin", which is less misleading but still not especially useful: the fact is, there's no great problem with just equating Mandarin /p/ with English /b/. Referring to words like "spin" is kind of an unnecessarily convoluted maneuver. (While the Chinese unaspirated stops are prototypically voiceless, they do have voiced allophones.)
For speakers of both English and Mandarin, prevoiced stops and unaspirated voiceless stops sound like the same sound. Although distinct on the phonetic level, speakers of these languages don't generally rely on that distinction alone to distinguish different words.
This is different from some other languages, such as Hindustani, where /p/, /b/, and aspirated /pʰ/ are all three distinct sounds (distinguished also from a fourth plosive /bʱ/). There are also some Chinese languages that distinguish /p/, /b/, and aspirated /pʰ/, e.g. apparently such a three-way distinction can be found in Wu Chinese. Among other things, transcribing Mandarin with /p pʰ/ instead of /b p/ makes it easier to accurately compare its sounds with those of other varieties of Chinese such as Wu.

And Middle Chinese also had 3-way distinction.

The phonetic distinction has already been explained but I just wanted to add my personal perception. As someone who speaks Finnish and English, while I can certainly tell the difference between Pinyin BDG and PTK, to me Pinyin BDG clearly sound closer to English PTK than they do to English BDG. (Not to say that they actually are, just pointing out how my native phonology causes me to hear them; creators of the original Wade-Giles orthography you were confused about may have felt the same way.)
As you mentioned other major Latin alphabet languages, I'd say that the Pinyin BDG sound (to me) largely identical to the sounds PTK which occur in Finnish and Spanish, while the Pinyin PTK sound like English PTK. There's nothing in Mandarin that would sound like e.g. a Spanish BDG.
In fact here is an example phrase Paljon kiitoksia which contains all three of the Finnish voiceless plosives. I'd be surprised if you perceive those as Mandarin PTK rather than Mandarin BDG, but I'm curious about your opinion.
